# Why We need different CSS for different browsers specially in case of IE(diff for IE6, IE7, 8, 9)

Tags: html, css

I am just curious to know that why default css doesn't works for all the browsers, specially it breaks for IE browsers(6,7,8,9). So usually we need to create different css files for different browsers (mainly for IE), why is that?

Comment: Ask Microsoft Internet Explorer Team go to them with psychoanalyst to know how that team thinking, myself, I hate IE and it's team.but I think maybe the answer is they was tring to re-create a wheel :|

Comment: @Al-Mothafar: as much as I dislike IE you are extremely over-simplifying the issue. IE is not the only browser with quirks. Think of the mess that all of the browsers vendors are currently doing in regards to mobile devices... Even more, think about how vendor prefixes (`-moz-`, `-o-`, `-webkit-`, `-ms-`, `-hp-` etc etc) can [render developing extremely impractical](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2012/07/vendor_prefixes.html)..

Comment: @nico thanks, but he asking about IE versions itself, its different from version to version, and from these versions to another browsers, prefixes not problem, because its like a customization you made for your own browser, but when you have a common property rendered differently from browser to browser, and from your browser to anther version of your browser ! you can ask why Microsoft too late too, about support some properties, like border-radius supported in IE9 while its supported from Ages in another browsers !

Comment: @Al-Mothafar: I do not agree. Prefixes are a BIG problem, because if you want to have CSS3 running in all browsers (and IE is not the only problem) you'll have to write the same thing in 3 or 4 different ways (see the `device-pixel-ratio` example linked above). It's not a "customization for your own browser", that is exactly MS logic (we do it our way).

Comment: @nico - The difference is IE does not follow the standard while vendor prefixes allow users to use new properties that are not finalized yet. Those prefixed properties will eventually lose the prefix while any one version of IE will never work correctly. By far, IE is the worst browser on the planet.

Comment: @Rob: never said the opposite. I'm just saying that blaming it on the MS dev team for the current "browser CSS chaos" situation is a bit naïve. You have to adjust your CSS for the other browsers too. Standard or non standard the problem remains. And, not to repeat the same point again, where would be the "standardness" in prefixed properties, if everyone codes them in a different way?

Comment: @nico - That's the point of vendor prefixes. They are a temporary situation and aren't intended to be applied to all browsers. Nor are they intended to be used for all properties forever. Eventually you stop using them for any one individual property once it settles down.

Comment: @Rob: So why `-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5` `min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5` and `-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2`. Why\ don't they all to 1.5? Why don't they all put min after the prefix? Why does Mozilla add an extra dash? Same thing with gradients where everyone (even ms) but webkit uses the same syntax (with their vendor prefix, of course).

Comment: Anything in a vendor prefix is non-standard or not finished. Sometimes experimental. You can't fault any browser for anything inside a vendor prefix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS is a big scary technology with no *official* implementation, only official specs.  This means that there is no STANDARD interpreter that defines how the language is supposed to be interpreted, only docs which guide interpreter makers.  The result is many interpreters, each with their own quirks and glitches.

...

*And then there's IE*

...

Microsoft has long held a firm foot in the "let's do it our way" ring.  There have been many reasons for this ranging from implementing features that the WC3 CSS standards don't, yet, support (for example, they had a very early version of the modern `opacity` command) to more sinister reasons like trying to force compliance with their standard making niche appeal for their browser.

Either way, if you're going into web-dev, IE is going to be the bane of your existence.  If you think CSS is bad, wait till you get to JS.

Comment: Nah, MS JS is pretty much either standard or have same quirks as other browsers. You must've thinking about DOM and its methods (that, BTW, can be accessed with other scripting languages as well). Now those **are** broken in IE.

Comment: AJAX, DOM, and CSS access (although the last of those is technically not a Javascript issue) are all pretty different in all but the most recent versions of IE.

Comment: Neither AJAX nor DOM is JS issue. None of those are defined in JS standard and both of them can be perfectly accessed through VB or Perl scripting for example.

Comment: I think you're missing the point, BOTH must be executed differently when using IE.  It doesn't matter if it's actually a Javascript issue, if the OP uses Javascript, they'll likely start using it to access those technologies and thus have problems.  I never said they were specific to Javascript.  Are we done parading our knowledge, yet?

Comment: It is not about "parading" or anything. Be clear. Don't spread misinformation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a fan of creating browser specific CSS and usually try to use a solution that will work in all browsers. The reasons for some things not working in different browsers are:

- bugs
- different interpretation of styling
- using something that was not implemented in the previous version

Answer (score 1):

Some browsers don't support all of the features CSS has to offer. 
Also in some cases you need to "fine-tune" the css specially for IE because of the "[css box model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug)". You may also need it to enable backwards compatibility for previous versions.

Answer (score 0):

It is needed when you implement some feature of css which is not provided in all browser.

Then someone need various css files for fallback.

suppose you are using `position:fixed;` in css and if you want your site to be perfect in ie6 then you will need some other css file for callback because `position:fixed;` is not supported in ie6